# Clearing frontpage everytime new data is added with docx

Tags: python, docx, editing, sections

I am using docx library to auto-generate a word document. I divided my document in sections where section[0] is the front-page (title and headers) and section[1] is the rest of the document.

How can I clear only section[0] so it does not appear again every time the document is edited/saved? Section[1] might always update and not overwrite.

```
def save_word_doc(self, filename):

    document = docx.Document()
    firstsection = document.sections[0]
    print('firstsection', firstsection)

    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('File exist')
        f = open(filename)
        document = Document(filename)

    else:
        print('File not exist')  # Creates a new file if it does not exist


    document.add_picture('title_page_title.png')
    document.add_heading('Title')


    document.add_picture('footer.png',
                         width=docx.shared.Inches(6))
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    document.add_heading(str(now))

    document.add_section(WD_SECTION.EVEN_PAGE)
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing what you want? A Word document has sections as you said. What prevents you from cleaning the second section's contents and adding new ones? Post your code

Comment: I tried to use body document._body.clear_content() but it clears the entire document. Is there a way to clear only the first section of the doc?

Comment: Post your code. We can't guess what you're talking about. Besides, you want to clear the *section*, not the document. Or just delete that section and add another

Comment: Deleting the section could also work. I have posted part of my code. Thanks

Comment: I found the solution using True and False statements